# why android idle duration is set to 71 mins

Tags: android

```
public class IdleController extends StateController {
private static final String TAG = "IdleController";
// Policy: we decide that we're "idle" if the device has been unused /
// screen off or dreaming for at least this long
private static final long INACTIVITY_IDLE_THRESHOLD = 71 * 60 * 1000; // millis; 71 min
```

Android system regards the device is idle if it is not active after this
INACTIVITY_IDLE_THRESHOLD duration.
Here is a number, 71 minutes.
Why 71 mins(not other number, such as 60), is there any story or reason ?

Comment: Why the `python-idle` tag?

Comment: @TDG Some people don't read tag explanations before using the tag.  Hence the use of the tag for Python's IDLE IDE (Shell + editor)  for any 'idle' in any language.  I remove such mis-uses when I see them.